# How to retrieve a record from a data extension field in SFMC using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, ssjs, data

In my SSJS, I am using this approach to retrieve the value / record from a data extension field.

- Data extension name is Test_QResult
- Data extension field name from where i want to retrieve value is DE_Name

  ```
  var DEnameInRows = DataExtension.Init("Test_QResult").Rows.Retrieve();

  var FromDEname = DEnameInRows[1].DE_Name;
  ```

**In my test, FromDEname is showing null - can anyone please help?**

```
Write(Stringify(FromDEname));
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/226202/39888), you need can't use the name of the DE in the `DataExtension.Init()` function, but need to use it's external key.

For example:

```
var DEnameInRows = DataExtension.Init("A1A1A1A1-B2B2-C3C3-D4D4-E5E5E5E5E5E5").Rows.Retrieve();

var FromDEname = DEnameInRows[1].DE_Name;
```

That's one option, but you could just simply change the external key (for example in Email Studio) to `Test_QResult` and your original code should start working.

---

You might already know this, but it could also come in play here:

If you would have only one record in the DE, you wouldn't be able to retrieve it with `DEnameInRows[1]`. In contrast to Ampscript where rowsets start with 1, arrays in JavaScript (and SSJS) start with 0 (are zero-indexed), so you would need to use `DEnameInRows[0].DE_Name`.